# Can I check internal data types of variables?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that does some heavy calculations and stores partial results in an array named A.
When I defined the array as Uint32Array(8) the code was over 2 times slower than when I defined the array as Array(8).
The calculations look like this:

```
A[0] = A[0] + (((A[3] ^ A[2]) & A[1]) ^ A[3]) + X[I] + 0x176ab448 + A[1];
```

I think that if A[0] is Uint32 (element of Uint32Array) it is slower because Java Script uses by default Floats for numbers and has to do some conversions.

If I made sure all the variables are Uint32 then it should be faster, right?

Can I somehow either check if a particular variable is internally stored as Uint32 or somehow force the browser to store a given variable always as Uint32 so all the computations are done on integers and not on floats (for performance reasons)?

Comment: For heavy calculations, you can try asm.js. Then browsers will do integer operations without converting to doubles.

Comment: @Oriol if I understand correctly to use asm.js I need first to convert C++ code with Emscripten?

Comment: Use a regular array. Determining whether a value is/remains an integer and storing it appropriately is already an optimization JavaScript engines do. And no, you don’t need to use Emscripten to use asm.js.

Comment: It's not worth micro-optimising _JavaScript_ like this. If you start with a _UInt32_ representable numbers, only use `+-*%&|^` and don't go over `0xFFFFFFFF` (or below `0` for _UInt_) then your resulting value is gauranteed to be representable as a _UInt32_. You will only have issues if you try to use `&|^` on numbers bigger _32 bits_, you may also need to consider what you want to do if a number exceeds `0x7FFFFFFF` and you want a _Uint32_ but it's stored as an _Int32_.

Comment: Additionally, `+-*` will work fine as integer operators up to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; // 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFF`